# Interceptor not being called but executes anyway?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, action, interceptor

I have two Interceptors defined in separate packages.

One is "affirmative" (checks if `session` contains `currentId`) and the other "non-affirmative" (checks if `session` does not contain `currentId`).

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<!-- actions available to guests -->
<package name="guest" extends="struts-default">
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="containskey" class="com.mypackage.interceptor.ContainsKeyInterceptor" />
    </interceptors>

    <action name="index" class="com.mypackage.action.IndexAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
        <interceptor-ref name="containskey" />
        <result type="redirect">/index.jsp</result>
        <result name="index" type="redirect">/index.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="login" class="com.mypackage.action.LoginAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
        <interceptor-ref name="containskey" />
        <result type="redirect">/index.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/login.jsp</result>
        <result name="index" type="redirect">/index.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>

<!-- actions available to members -->
<package name="member" extends="struts-default">
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="notcontainskey" class="com.mypackage.interceptor.NotContainsKeyInterceptor" />
    </interceptors>

    <action name="changepassword" class="com.mypackage.action.ChangePasswordAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
        <interceptor-ref name="notcontainskey" />
        <result type="redirect">/usercp.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/usercp-change-password.jsp</result>
        <result name="index" type="redirect">/index.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="logout" class="com.mypackage.action.LogoutAction">
        <result type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">index</param>
        </result>
    </action>
</package>
```

**`NotContainsKeyInterceptor`:**

```
public class NotContainsKeyInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("NotContainsKeyInterceptor");

        final ActionContext actionContext = actionInvocation.getInvocationContext();
        Map<String, Object> session = actionContext.getSession();

        if(!session.containsKey("currentId")) {
            return "index";
        }

        String result = actionInvocation.invoke();

        return result;
    }
}
```

`http://localhost:8080/mysite/changepassword`

1. When I call the `changepassword` action without logging in (i.e.
   `session` does not contain `currentId`), the `println()` of the
   `NotContainsKeyInterceptor` is not executing (which makes me assume
   it is not being called), yet, it does the expected behavior of
   redirecting to `index.jsp`.
2. The `validate()` method of `ChangePasswordAction` class is also
   being called.

Why is this so?

(Please do tell me if you need to see the `ChangePasswordAction` class, I will add it to the post.)

Comment: Actually its not being called.. Can you change your configuration this way and try  `<interceptor-ref name="notcontainskey" /> <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
        ` I mean specify your interceptor first later `defaultstack`

Comment: Interchanging worked. If you could put that as a formal answer, I will accpet it. Thanks. :)

Comment: Interceptor are invoked in the order specified by the configuration elements.

Comment: @RomanC, if I had other interceptors, does the `defaultStack` always go last?

Comment: No, if it's not breaking a chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually its not being called.. Can you change your configuration this way and try

```
    <interceptor-ref name="notcontainskey" /> 
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
```

I mean specify your interceptor first later defaultstack